# read socket from C

Tags: c, sockets

When I use `read()` socket to retrieval bytes from server I found something unexpected in the chars.

Below is my code:

```
Char buf[80];
Char output[80];
if ( (count = read(socket_d, buf, 80)) == -1) {
        perror("Error on read call");
        exit(1);
    }
strcat(output, buf);
printf("Client read %d bytes\n", count);       
while (count==80) {
    memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    if ( (count = read(socket_d, buf, 80)) == -1) {
        perror("Error on read call");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Client read %d bytes\n", count);
    strcat(output, buf);
}
/* print the received message */
printf("\n%s\n\n", output);
```

The output as below:

```
Client read 80 bytes
Client read 80 bytes
Client read 8 bytes
Your messages:
1:From User1, 04/21/16 02:12 AM, MSG1
2:From User2, 04/21/16 02:162 AM, MSG2
3:From User2, 04/21/16 02:12 AM, MSG3
4:From User1, 04/21/16 02:12 AM6, MSG4
```

The expect output should be:

```
Client read 80 bytes
Client read 80 bytes
Client read 8 bytes
Your messages:
1:From User1, 04/21/16 02:12 AM, MSG1
2:From User2, 04/21/16 02:12 AM, MSG2
3:From User2, 04/21/16 02:12 AM, MSG3
4:From User1, 04/21/16 02:12 AM, MSG4
```

It seems that there is unexpected `char('6')` shown in `buf[]` in the second loop.

As I define the size of each time `read()` socket, so I want to loop read until the read amount is less than the `limit_size`, then output.

What should I do with the `buf[]` during the loop to avoid the unexpected chars?

Comment: What exactly is `Char`?

Comment: Any issues in intializing? `strcat()` may fail OW.

Comment: `output` is used before initialized.  Run your program with valgrind to detect such errors.

Comment: Could you print what you just read from socket before concatening it? It will help to see in which part the problem is.

Comment: You can maybe add which socket API you use (linux, windows?)

Comment: Read 80 bytes into `buf`, copy them to `output`, which is 80 bytes, then read another 80 bytes and append them to `output`. Don't think this will work all that well.

Comment: 'strcat(output, buf); - use of str* calls on char arrays that are not guaranteed null-terminated.

Comment: The read() call does not have to read 80 bytes.  It returns how many it loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- `output` is used uninitialized in

```
strcat(output, buf);
```

2- `memset` wants a pointer and `buf` is already (decays into) a pointer

```
memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
```

should be

```
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
```

3- If `count == 80` then you have no space for the trailing `NUL` in your buffer, declare `buf`as `char buf[81];` (or `read` 79 bytes) and don't forget to end your string with `\0` after `read()`

```
buf[count] = '\0';
```

Comment: Where are the stray characters coming from when reading from the socket?

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury `output` is too small. When you add more than 80 characters to it you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: 'buf' is not guaranteed null-terminated.   'count' is the ONLY way of determining how many bytes have been loaded into the buffer/s.  str* calls are sanely unuseable, expecially if the data being transferred has zero bytes embedded in it.